# RaveDb/Lucene - Price Range query not working when start range is zero

Tags: lucene, ravendb

I am using RavenDb for our Product Catalog. When I click into a category, I see my 5 products in that category, where one of the products is listed at 0.00. If I adjust my price range facet, for example I bring down the max price and the min price stays at 0, the zero priced product no longer appears when it still falls within the range. This only happens when the min range is zero, any other time when the min is greater than zero, the query works exactly as expected. This is the query being executed in Raven.

```
{Category:(categories/1839) AND Price_Range:[Dx0 TO Dx139]}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but try querying by either `[Dx0.0 TO Dx139.0]` or `[NULL TO Dx139.0]`